# Elastic beanstalk not support on custom AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, elastic-beanstalk

I have launched a default Amazon ElasticBeanstalk image(php) in EC2 .I can able to deployed application on Apache.I am trying to use a custom AMI in AWS Beanstalk and does not get deployed on the instance.

How to use custom AMI?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a custom AMI with elastic beanstalk, you have to install cloud-init on your AMI and launch it automatically during boot.

More information here:
[Using Custom AMIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html)

Comment: How to install the cloud-init on ubuntu?

Comment: root@ip-172-30-1-202:~# apt-get install cloud-init
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cloud-init is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded

Comment: It's showing package is installed.